# Issue with jQuery lightbox plugin overlay

Tags: jquery, html, forms, lightbox, kentico

i have a strange issue whilst using the lightbox plugin where the overlay for it (the greyish black bg that normally shows when clicking an `<a>`) is displayed at the bottom of my page and doesn't close when the user clicks off the image. This is a little hard to describe so here's an image illustrating the problem:

[image]

Clicking this then creates the overlay at the bottom of the page outside of the `<form>` element with the image further down, like so:

[image]

The rendered image markup looks as follows:

```
<div id="lightbox-gallery">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="/what-does-it-do/submit-annual-returns/lightboxobjects/forbury-large1/" rel="lightbox[group]" rev="/What-does-it-do/Submit-Annual-Returns/LightboxObjects/forbury-large1" title="Fobury court"><img src="/getattachment/819283f6-7436-40dc-9401-9f8194efc0e8/forbury-large1?maxsidesize=150" alt="forbury-large1"></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The jQuery is:

```
$(function () {
    $('#lightbox-gallery ul li a').lightBox();
});
```

Am i missing something obvious here? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Are you importing the Lightbox Css file? It seems the correct styles aren't being applied to the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with very basic setting as described here (Just for testing)

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

I hope you are using the same plugin.